# CORS Asp.Net Core through the appsetting.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

the idea is that the application I'm working in backand - when I forward to forendend that they in one place through a configuration file eg appsettings.json allow them to change access information in it. As has the ability for the connecting string to the database.
I make this in appsetings file:

```
 "CORSConfiguration": {
    "WithOrigin": "",
    "WithMethod": "*",
    "WithHeader": "*",
    "WithCredentials": "*"
  },
```

In WithOrigin thay will insert requested resources, WithMethod requesed methods etc...
Then I create interface:

```
public interface ICORSConfiguration
    {
        List<string> WithOrigin { get; set; }
        List<string> WithMethod { get; set; }
        List<string> WithHeader { get; set; }
        List<string> WithCredentials { get; set; }
    }
```

Then I create class which inherit this interface:

```
public class CORSConfiguration: ICORSConfiguration
{
   public List<string> WithOrigin { get; set; }
   public List<string> WithMethod { get; set; }
   public List<string> WithHeader { get; set; }
   public List<string> WithCredentials { get; set; }
}
```

do you have any advice on how to do this, what are the possibilities here ...?
How do I install these controls in the controller ... I have no idea how to complete this.
I need this for REST application that only has the Mail method to send an email.
The method looks like:

```
[HttpPost("send")]
        public void Send(EmailMessage emailMessage)
        {

            var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(emailMessage.Email, emailMessage.Name));
            message.To.AddRange(emailMessage.To.Select(c => new MailboxAddress(c.Email)));
            message.Cc.AddRange(emailMessage.Cc.Select(c => new MailboxAddress(c.Email)));
            message.Bcc.AddRange(emailMessage.Bcc.Select(c => new MailboxAddress(c.Email)));

            message.Subject = emailMessage.Subject;

            message.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html)
            {
                Text = emailMessage.Message
            };
            CorsService corsService = new CorsService();
            corsService.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet(Array.("*")));

            //_corsConfiguration.WithHeader
            //_corsConfiguration.WithMethod;

            using (var emailClient = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
            {
                //emailClient.Connect(_emailConfiguration.SmtpServer, _emailConfiguration.SmtpPort, true);
                emailClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465);
                //emailClient.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                emailClient.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
                emailClient.Authenticate(_emailConfiguration.SmtpUsername, _emailConfiguration.SmtpPassword);
                //emailClient.
                emailClient.Send(message);
                emailClient.Disconnect(true);
            }

        }
```

With this CorsServices I try something, that don work...

Answer (score 0):

Cors needs to be enables on the server. So if you call x webservice then that service has to enable cors support. You can do this either on controller lebel or much better to do it on startup class. See here for more details.

You do not need to create classes and app settings valies.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I did it, but I'm wondering if there is a solution as it is intended, through appsettings.json file...